# I created a game, but the counter for wins, losses and draws isn't working

Tags: java, counter

One would think that this would be the easiest thing (it should be right), but my JLabel values are not being updated to reflect that the game is a draw, loss or win. I initiate 3 variables (numLosses, numDraws, and numWins), and then I increment them each time there is a loss, win or draw. However my counter remains at 0? Why? Here is the code?

NewTicTacToe.java:

```
package newtictactoe;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class NewTicTacToe
    extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new NewTicTacToe();
    }

    private JButton btnA1, btnA2, btnA3, btnB1, btnB2, btnB3, btnC1, btnC2, btnC3;
        private JLabel lblWins, lblLosses, lblDraws;

    private TicTacToeBoard board;
        private int numWins, numDraws, numLosses;

    public NewTicTacToe()
    {
        // Set up the grid
                this.numDraws = 0;
                this.numWins = 0;
                this.numLosses = 0;
        this.setSize(800,450);
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
                panel1.setSize(650,450); //resolution of panel1 set to 650 by 325
                panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
                btnA1 = createButton("A1");
                btnA2 = createButton("A2");
                btnA3 = createButton("A3");
                btnB1 = createButton("B1");
                btnB2 = createButton("B2");
                btnB3 = createButton("B3");
                btnC1 = createButton("C1");
                btnC2 = createButton("C2");
                btnC3 = createButton("C3");
        panel1.add(btnA1);
        panel1.add(btnA2);
        panel1.add(btnA3);
        panel1.add(btnB1);
        panel1.add(btnB2);
        panel1.add(btnB3);
        panel1.add(btnC1);
        panel1.add(btnC2);
        panel1.add(btnC3);
                JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                lblWins = new JLabel("Wins: " + numWins);
                lblLosses = new JLabel("Losses: " + numLosses);
                lblDraws = new JLabel("Draws: " + numDraws);


                panel2.add(lblWins);
                panel2.add(lblLosses);
                panel2.add(lblDraws);

                lblWins.setLocation(670, 20);
                lblLosses.setLocation(670, 50);
                lblDraws.setLocation(670, 80);

                lblWins.setSize(100, 20);
                lblLosses.setSize(100, 20);
                lblDraws.setSize(100, 20);

                panel2.setLayout(null);



        this.add(panel1);
            this.add(panel2);
        this.setVisible(true);

        // Start the game and create new instance of TicTacToeBoard
        board = new TicTacToeBoard();

    }

    private JButton createButton(String square)
    {
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        Font f = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 72);
        btn.setFont(f);
        btn.addActionListener(e -> btnClick(e, square));
        return btn;
    }

    private void btnClick(ActionEvent e, String square)
    {
        if (board.getSquare(square) != 0)
            return;

        JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();
        btn.setText("X");


        board.playAt(square, 1);

        if (board.isGameOver() == 3)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "It's a draw!", "Game Over",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                numDraws++;
            resetGame();
            return;
        }

        if (board.isGameOver() == 1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "You Win n00b!", "Game Over",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                numWins++;

            resetGame();
            return;
        }

        String computerMove = board.getNextMove();
        board.playAt(computerMove,2);

        switch (computerMove)
        {
            case "A1":
                btnA1.setText("O");
                break;
            case "A2":
                btnA2.setText("O");
                break;
            case "A3":
                btnA3.setText("O");
                break;
            case "B1":
                btnB1.setText("O");
                break;
            case "B2":
                btnB2.setText("O");
                break;
            case "B3":
                btnB3.setText("O");
                break;
            case "C1":
                btnC1.setText("O");
                break;
            case "C2":
                btnC2.setText("O");
                break;
            case "C3":
                btnC3.setText("O");
                break;
        }

        if (board.isGameOver() == 2)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Computer wins you big n00b!", "Game Over",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                numLosses++;
            resetGame();
            return;
        }
    }



    private void resetGame()
    {
        board.reset();
        btnA1.setText("");
        btnA2.setText("");
        btnA3.setText("");
        btnB1.setText("");
        btnB2.setText("");
        btnB3.setText("");
        btnC1.setText("");
        btnC2.setText("");
        btnC3.setText("");
    }
}
```

TicTacToeBoard.java:

```
package newtictactoe;

public class TicTacToeBoard
{
    int numWins = 0;
        int numLosses = 0;
        int numDraws = 0;

        private int board [];

    private int vectors [] [] =
        {
               {0, 1, 2},    // Row 1
           {3, 4, 5},    // Row 2
           {6, 7, 8},    // Row 3
           {0, 3, 6},    // Column 1
           {1, 4, 7},    // Column 2
           {2, 5, 8},    // Column 3
           {0, 4, 8},    // Diagonal 1
           {2, 4, 6}     // Diagonal 2
        };

    public TicTacToeBoard()
    {
        this.reset();
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        board = new int[] {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
    }

    private int getSquare(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 | index > 8)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("index must be 0-9");

        return board[index];
    }

    public int getSquare(String square)
    {
        int index = mapSquareToIndex(square);
        if (index == -1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid square");
        switch (getSquare(index))
        {
            case 3:
                return 1;
            case 5:
                return 2;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    private int mapSquareToIndex(String square)
    {
        switch (square)
        {
            case "A1":
                return 0;
            case "A2":
                return 1;
            case "A3":
                return 2;
            case "B1":
                return 3;
            case "B2":
                return 4;
            case "B3":
                return 5;
            case "C1":
                return 6;
            case "C2":
                return 7;
            case "C3":
                return 8;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    private String mapIndexToSquare(int index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                return "A1";
            case 1:
                return "A2";
            case 2:
                return "A3";
            case 3:
                return "B1";
            case 4:
                return "B2";
            case 5:
                return "B3";
            case 6:
                return "C1";
            case 7:
                return "C2";
            case 8:
                return "C3";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }


    public void playAt(String square, int player)
    {
        int index = mapSquareToIndex(square);
        if (index == -1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid square");
        this.playAt(index, player);
    }

    private void playAt(int index, int player)
    {
        if (index < 0 | index > 8)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Square must be 0-8");
        if (player <1 | player > 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Player must be 1 or 2");
        if (board[index] != 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Square is not empty.");
        if (player == 1)
            board[index] = 3;
        else
            board[index] = 5;
    }

    public int isGameOver()
    {
        // check for win
        for (int v = 0; v < 8; v++)
        {
            int p = getVectorProduct(v);
            if (p == 27) {
                            numWins++;
                return 1; 
                        }                // Player 1 has won
            if (p == 125) {
                            numLosses++;
                return 2;  
                            // Player 2 has won
                        }
        }

        // check for draw

        int blankCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            if (board[i] == 2)
                blankCount++;
        if (blankCount == 0) {
                numDraws++;
            return 3;          // Game is a draw
            }
        return 0;              // Game is not over
    }

    public String canPlayerWin(int player)
    {
        if (player <1 | player > 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("player must be 1 or 2");

        boolean playerCanWin = false;

        for (int v = 0; v < 8; v++)
        {
            int p = getVectorProduct(v);
            if (   (player == 1 & p == 18)
                 | (player == 2 & p == 50) )
                            {
                if (board[vectors[v][0]] == 2)
                    return mapIndexToSquare(vectors[v][0]);
                if (board[vectors[v][1]] == 2)
                    return mapIndexToSquare(vectors[v][1]);
                if (board[vectors[v][2]] == 2)
                    return mapIndexToSquare(vectors[v][2]);
                            }
        }
        return "";


    }
    private int getVectorProduct(int vector)
    {
        return board[vectors[vector][0]] *
               board[vectors[vector][1]] *
               board[vectors[vector][2]];
    }

    public String getNextMove()
    {
        String bestMove;

        // Win if possible
        bestMove = this.canPlayerWin(2);
        if (bestMove != "")
            return bestMove;

        // Block if necessary
        bestMove = this.canPlayerWin(1);
        if (bestMove != "")
            return bestMove;

        // Center if it is open
        if (board[4] == 2)
            return "B2";

        // First open corner
        if (board[0] == 2)
            return "A1";
        if (board[2] == 2)
            return "A3";
        if (board[6] == 2)
            return "C1";
        if (board[8] == 2)
            return "C3";

        // First open edge
        if (board[1] == 2)
            return "A2";
        if (board[3] == 2)
            return "B1";
        if (board[5] == 2)
            return "B3";
        if (board[7] == 2)
            return "C2";

        return "";          // The board is full
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return " " +
               getMark(board[0]) + " | " +
               getMark(board[1]) + " | " +
               getMark(board[2]) +
               "\n-----------\n" +
               " " +
               getMark(board[3]) + " | " +
               getMark(board[4]) + " | " +
               getMark(board[5]) +
               "\n-----------\n" +
               " " +
               getMark(board[6]) + " | " +
               getMark(board[7]) + " | " +
               getMark(board[8]);
    }


    private String getMark(int status)
    {
        if (status == 3)
            return "X";
        if (status == 5)
            return "O";
        return " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Please make it *obvious* what section of code you're referring to. I imagine most of this is irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never updating the JLabels after you update numLosses, numDraws, and numWins. Do this by using

```
lblWins.setText(Integer.toString(numWins));
lblLosses.setText(Integer.toString(numLosses));
lblDraws.setText(Integer.toString(numDraws));
```

at the appropriate places

Answer (score 2):

In the file newTicTacToe.java, after every game you are updating the count in the variables `numWins`, `numDraws` and `numLosses`.

You need to update the JLabels lblWins, lblDraws and lblLosses too.

In your reset function, also add:

```
lblWins.setText("Wins: " + numWins);
lblLosses.setText("Losses: " + numLosses);
lblDraws.setText("Draws: " + numDraws);
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are only updating the int variables, `numWins`, `numDraws`, `numLosses`.

Changing the value of a variable does not change your labels' texts. How can the computer know that your labels are "linked" with the variables?

The solution is easy, just as you said. You just need to set the text of the labels whenever you change the value of the variables.

```
numWins++;
lblWins.setText(Integer.toString(numWins));
```

"But I will forget to do this sometimes!" you shouted. That's why you should add "setter" methods like this one:

```
private void setNumWins(int value) {
    numWins = value;
    lblWins.setText(Integer.toString(value));
}
```

Now, you can just call `setNumWins` and the label will update as well:

```
setNumWins(numWins + 1);
```

Isn't this just wonderful?